# Icons not showing up properly and settings not opening (using tweaks)

Tags: settings, tweak-tool

I'm a new user of elementary and don't know anything about linux (I wanted to use an other system than windows bcause it wiped a partition and corrupted my hard drive during an update). So I just follow little tutorials from the ubuntu community without asking too many questions, but i ran into an issue (and it's completly my fault, sorry).

I wanted to change the theme to a dark theme and discovered tweaks. Then I installed it (https://techsphinx.com/linux/install-elementary-tweaks/)
And on the gnome looks website I downloaded a macOS theme to match the OS.
Everything worked fine, so I thought "let's install an icon pack" (very bad idea for a non experimented guy like me).

I googled how to install an icon pack and it says to extract the pack in to /usr/share/icons/
and to select it in the settings, but when I had done that every icon disapeared and the settings won't open, I can't delete the pack: I tried "sudo rmdir /usr/share/icons/McMojave-circle-black-dark" and the terminal says rmdir: impossible de supprimer 'McMojave-circle-black-dark/': Le dossier n'est pas vide, it's obviously in frensh because my system is in frensh and says something like "rmdir: impossible to remove 'McMojave-circle-black-dark/': The folder is not empty" I know that it's not empty, that is the reason why i want to remove it !!!

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'elementary'` in Terminal, see if that sets your theme back to default. To remove a directory AND its contents, add '-r' after the command: `sudo rmdir -r /usr/share/icons/McMojave-circle-black-dark`. Fair warning -> try not to use sudo and rmdir without knowing what you;re doing :D

Answer (score 1):

all stuff for icons/themes has to be put into a local folder of your session /home/name/.icons (create a hidden folder .icons)
why to put icons theme in systeme disk. On my own elementary i have all systeme folders untouchable, why to play the guy who want to do all stuff in the systeme folders. Don't touch them, you are not experienced,proof : you don't know what's going on now, just with icons folder...